# Find string position in text (Python, TkInter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I find the position of a specific text string inside my text?

For example, I have the text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", and when I search for "ipsum" I want to find out its position.

```
if "ipsum" in text:
    print position


else:
    pass
```

The position I'm looking for is something like "1.6"
If I want to change the color of the text it looks like this:

```
text.tag_add("foo", "1.28", "1.39")
```

Then in order to change the color of the text that I''ve searched for I need to get its postion somehow, right? I could be wrong but I'm looking for some example or guidance.
Thanks! :)

Comment: what do you mean by 'The position I'm looking for is something like "1.6"'? what does 1.6 represent? First row, 6th column?

Comment: If I want to change the color of the text it looks like this:
text.tag_add("foo", "1.28", "1.39")
Then in order to change the color of the text that I''ve searched for I need to get its postion somehow, right? I could be wrong but I'm looking for some example or guidance.
Thanks! :)

Comment: I removed the tkinter tag, since this question seems to have nothing to do with tkinter. You're simply asking how to search a string for a substring.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464813/explain-tkinter-text-search-method?

Comment: Removing the tkinter tag was a mistake -- that "x.y" position notation is how the tkinter text widget identifies positions within the widget.

Comment: You are asking about searching a text string for a substring, but is your real question how to search for, and highlight, text in a text widget? What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to highlight surten string in my text.

Comment: David, you need to be more precise in your language. When you say "in my text", do you mean "in my text _widget_" or "in my text _string_"?  The solution to highlighting something in a string is different than highlighting something in a text widget, and the solution to the former doesn't necessarily lead to a solution in the latter. If your ultimate goal is to highlight text in a text widget, that is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464813/explain-tkinter-text-search-method

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Text.search()` function, e.g

```
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
pos = text.search('ipsum', '1.0', stopindex=END)
print pos
```

This should output `1.6`.

To highlight the target string you can use `tag_add()` and `tag_config()`...

```
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert(INSERT, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
target = 'ipsum'
start_pos = text.search(target, '1.0', stopindex=END)
print '{!r}'.format(start_pos)
if start_pos:
    end_pos = '{}+{}c'.format(start_pos, len(target))
    print '{!r}'.format(end_pos)
    text.tag_add('highlight', start_pos, end_pos)
    text.tag_config('highlight', foreground='red')

root.mainloop()
```

If you would like to search for all instances of a word within the text widget, or more than one word, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29316232/21945

Comment: This will now help me, but thank you to giving the effort for helping.

Comment: @DavidOlsson: no problem. If this answered your question you should consider marking it as accepted.